# Converting massive .bak files to .parquet for upload to BigQuery

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-backups

I have 12 files, each around 20GB, on Google Drive, that are database backups in a `.bak` file format. I'd like to upload them to BigQuery for analysis, however, BigQuery cannot handle `.bak` files and requires `csv` or `parquet` files. I am currently planning on downloading each file to a local machine, uploading it to Microsoft's SQL Studio, converting it to `.parquet`, and then uploading *that* file to BigQuery from my local machine (laptop), but this is long and painful. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not really, unless you use an external tool. Maybe ApexSQL Litespeed can do this

Comment: We are looking to do something similar (.bak to parquet)
Were you able to find a solution? We want it to be part of a step function that runs daily...

Comment: Nothing yet! Ending up trying to do this by hand :(

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar. Moving multiple dbs to big query but don't seem to find a simpler way than by hand. How did you end up doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the worst step I am thinking to copy .bak files to the storage account. create SQL on VM with massive memory and then run an ADF to copy SQL data to Parquet. unless anyone else has a better option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No joy so far, only answer I see is to use Azure CI and a Docker to convert the .bak to bacpac and restore it to an SQL instance :

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/using-an-azure-container-instance-to-convert-a-bak-to-bacpac-for-import-into-azure-sql-database/